# How do i write and access scope rules and variables in ANTLR for C#

Tags: c#, scope, antlr, rules

How do I use scope rules and variables in ANTLR for C#? I have the following rough example:

```
    countInt returns[int val]
    scope{int i;}
    @init{ $countInt::i=0;}
   : (INT{$countInt::i++;val=i;)+
   ;

   INT:[0..9]+ ;
```

This clearly will not work using the ANTLR C# target. What is the right way to access  and write scope rules and variables?

Answer (score 0):

That syntax appears to work in Antlr 3.5.0.2 (http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr3CSharpReleases)